# Navigate to File fuzzy search - Ignore path separator

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

Suppose I have the path

```
/hello/world/file.txt
```

In other editors such as Atom, Sublime Text or Visual Studio Code, when navigating to the file using fuzzy search (CTRL+P), I can for example input `hewofi` and the editor shows me this file as search-result. In PhpStorm however, I have to use directory-separators, i.e. `he\wo\fi` otherwise it doesn't find the file.

How can I configure PhpStorm so that it's fuzzy search ignores path separators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>No way.</s> Now possible.

AFAIK (although not 100% sure) originally `Navigate | File` worked on file names only -- ability to also include path names was added later .. and you have to use them to denote that those letters are belonging to the path rather than file.

---

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112841 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

**UPDATE 2017-10-28:** the aforementioned ticket is now implemented and will be available in 2017.3 (you can grab EAP build if you wish to test it before the official release).

Comment: This makes me moderately angry.

Comment: @Spacemudd Why?

Comment: Well, the idea we can't fuzzy search (+ ignore speratores) breaks my workflow. Nevertheless, I just saw from the thread that the pre-release version have got the feature implemented! (Maybe the answer should be update?). I feel ok now, lol.

Comment: @Spacemudd Good :) BTW -- initial implementation was bugged as f£$% .. so it broke the ordinary search... **P.S.** Yeah -- I'll have to update the answer now.